# Linked Click for maps in Plotly R

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, geospatial, r-plotly

Data :

https://www.kaggle.com/wood2174/mapkickstarter

So i have a map im making with shiny and plotly and id like to click on a state and then pull up that state to get info on the counties in that state. Well iv seen other linked plot examples in plotly but I am not sure how to set up my map in this way. this is my plot before clicking. [image]

This is my map after iv clicked a state:
[image]

I am pretty sure I am not passing arguments the correct way between the two using the event_data argument. 
The argument i am passing is going to be the name of the state and that name will be pout into my function called CT as a character as to call up the state name so i can find the county data from clicked on state, the other, data and pop are two other data frames being passed into the function. 
This is what the function douse outside of shiny server and it produces and interactive hover map:
[image]

Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(
  navbarPage(
    "Kickstarter",
    navbarMenu(
      "Maps",
      tabPanel("US Map", plotlyOutput(
        "plotMap", height = 900, width = 1200
      )),
      tabPanel("County Map",
               plotlyOutput("Smap"),
               plotlyOutput("Cmap"))
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Interaction",
      plotlyOutput("plotInt", height = 900, width = 1200)
    ),
    navbarMenu(
      "Barplots",
      tabPanel("Citys", plotlyOutput(
        "plotBar1", height = 900, width = 1200
      )),
      tabPanel(
        "Catigories",
        plotlyOutput("plotBar2", height = 900, width = 1200)
      )
    )
  )
))


     server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #add reactive data information. Dataset = built in diamonds data
  H <- read_csv("C:/Users/clint/Documents/R/Personal work/Masters Project/MasterKickstarter.csv")
  M <- read_csv("C:/Users/clint/Documents/R/Personal work/Masters Project/data sets/Mapping.csv")
  C <- read_csv("C:/Users/clint/Documents/R/Personal work/Masters Project/data sets/County.csv")

  H <- as.data.frame(H)
  M <- as.data.frame(M)
  C <- as.data.frame(C)

  ### Plotting top twenty citys for a kick ###
  # calculate frequencies
  tab <- table(H$City)
  # sort
  tab_s <- sort(tab)
  # extract 10 most frequent nationalities
  top10 <- tail(names(tab_s), 25)
  # subset of data frame
  d_s <- subset(H, City %in% top10)
  # order factor levels
  d_s$City <- factor(d_s$City, levels = rev(top10))

  #function for capitalization
  simpleCap <- function(x) {
    s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)),
          substring(s, 2),
          sep = "",
          collapse = " ")
  }



  M$code <- state.abb[match(M$State, state.name)]

  #making temp sets that fit for interactive maps
  H = H[!duplicated(H[, "City"], fromLast = T), ]
  H$State <- sapply(as.character(H$State), simpleCap)
  H$code <- state.abb[match(H$State, state.name)]

  H$City <- factor(H$City)

  #making quartiles for plotting size
  H$q <-
    with(H, cut(All_Time_Backers_city, quantile(All_Time_Backers_city)))
  levels(H$q) <-
    paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"), "Quantile")
  H$q <- as.ordered(H$q)


  CT <- function(r,data,pop){

    cali <- map_data("county") %>%
      filter(region == r)

    cali_pop <- left_join(cali, pop, by = c("subregion","region"))

    cali_pop$pop_cat <- with(cali_pop,
                             (paste0(cali_pop$subregion, "<br />",
                                     round(cali_pop$MedianBackers), "Median Backers ||",round(cali_pop$MedianUSD),"MedianUSD","<br />",
                                     round(cali_pop$MeanBackers), "Mean Backers ||",round(cali_pop$MeanUSD),"MeanUSD","<br />",
                                     (cali_pop$TotalBackers), "Total Backers ||",(cali_pop$TotalUSD), "TotalUSD")))
    cali_pop[is.na(cali_pop)] <- 0
    cali_pop$pop_cat <- as.factor(cali_pop$pop_cat)

    p <- cali_pop %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~pop_cat, colors = c('#ffeda0','#f03b20')) %>%
      add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4),showlegend = FALSE) %>%
      add_polygons(
        fillcolor = 'transparent',
        line = list(color = 'black', width = 0.5),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>%
      layout(
        title = "Backers by County",
        titlefont = list(size = 10),
        xaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE,
                     zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
        yaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE,
                     zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
      )
    p

  }  

  output$Smap <- renderPlotly({
    M$hover <- with(M, paste(State))
    # give state boundaries a white border
    l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = 'north america',
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("grey83"),
      subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white"),
      showsubunits = TRUE,
      showcountries = TRUE,
      resolution = 50,
      projection = list(type = 'conic conformal',
                        rotation = list(lon = -100)),
      lonaxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(-140,-55),
        dtick = 5
      ),
      lataxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(15, 70),
        dtick = 5
      )
    )

    # Plotting a US interactive map
    p <- plot_geo(source = "CCM") %>%
      add_trace(M,
        z = ~ M$`Mean Bakers`,
        text = ~ M$hover,
        x = ~M$State,
        locations = ~ M$code,
        locationmode = "USA-states"
      ) %>%
      colorbar(title = "Money") %>%
      layout(
        title = 'Kickstarter USA',
        geo = g
      )
    p
  })

  output$Cmap <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "CCM")

    if (length(s)){

      var <- s[["x"]]
      d <- setNames(M[var], "x")
      CT(d,H,C)
    }
  })

  output$plotBar1 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- d_s %>% count(City, status) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~ City,
              y = ~ n,
              color = ~ status)
    p1

  })

  output$plotBar2 <- renderPlotly({
      p2 <- H %>% count(Categories, status) %>%
        plot_ly(x = ~ Categories,
                y = ~ n,
                color = ~ status)

      p2
    })

  output$plotMap <- renderPlotly({
    #preparing the hover text
    M$hover <- with(
      M,
      paste(
        State,
        '<br>',
        "Pledges_total",
        M$`Total Pledged`,
        "Backers_total",
        M$`Total Backers`,
        "<br>",
        "Mean_pledges",
        M$`Mean Campaign USD`,
        "Mean_backers",
        M$`Mean Bakers`,
        "<br>",
        "Median Goal %",
        M$`Median Percent of Goal`,
        "Number of projects",
        M$`Projects Per`
      )
    )

    g <- list(
      scope = 'north america',
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("grey83"),
      subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white"),
      showsubunits = TRUE,
      showcountries = TRUE,
      resolution = 50,
      projection = list(type = 'conic conformal',
                        rotation = list(lon = -100)),
      lonaxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(-140,-55),
        dtick = 5
      ),
      lataxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(15, 70),
        dtick = 5
      )
    )

    #plotting an interactive map for states and cities
    p <- plot_geo(H, sizes = c(5, 250)) %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~ H$Longitude,
        y = ~ H$Latitude,
        size = ~ H$All_Time_Backers_city,
        color = ~ q,
        text = ~ paste(H$City, "<br />",
                       H$All_Time_Backers_city, "Backers")
      ) %>%
      add_trace(M,
                z = ~ M$`Mean Campaign USD`,
                text = ~ M$hover,
                locations = ~ M$code
                ,
                locationmode = "USA-states"
      ) %>%
      layout(title = 'Backers City All Time', geo = g)
    p

  })

  output$plotInt <- renderPlotly({
    p <- H %>%
      plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        type = 'parcoords',
        line = list(
          color = ~ backers_count,
          colorscale = 'Jet',
          showscale = TRUE,
          reversescale = TRUE,
          cmin = 2,
          cmax = 1500
        ),
        dimensions = list(
          list(
            range = c(0, 92),
            constrantrange = c(0, 30),
            label = 'Time',
            values = ~ Length_of_kick
          ),
          list(
            range = c(0, 2000),
            constraintrange = c(0, 1000),
            label = 'Pledge USD',
            values = ~ Pledge_per_person
          ),
          list(
            range = c(0, 8000000),
            constrantrange = c(0, 3000000),
            label = 'Population',
            values = ~ MasterKickstarter$City_Pop
          ),
          list(
            range = c(0, 1600),
            constraintrange = c(0, 500),
            label = 'Days Making',
            values = ~ Days_spent_making_campign
          ),
          list(
            tickvals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            ticktext = c('cancled', 'failed', 'live', 'successful', 'suspended'),
            label = 'Status',
            values = ~ as.integer(as.factor(status))
          ),
          list(
            range = c(0, 1000000),
            constraintrange = c(0, 300000),
            label = 'Goal',
            values = ~ goal
          ),
          list(
            tickvals = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
            ticktext = c(
              'art',
              'comics',
              'crafts',
              'dance',
              'design',
              'fasion',
              'film',
              'food',
              'games',
              'journalism',
              'music',
              'photogaphy',
              'publishing',
              'technology',
              'theator'
            ),
            label = 'Catigories',
            values = ~ as.integer(as.factor(Categories))
          ),
          list(
            range = c( ~ min(Prct_goal), 1200),
            constraintrange = c(0, 500),
            label = 'Prct goal',
            values = ~ Prct_goal
          )
        )
      )
    p
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: your UI is missing.

Comment: Ok its up there, i did not post the whole server because it all works so far but not this part of the server and did not want to place to much code up there.

Comment: can you recheck your server. it does not work.

Comment: ok i posted the whole server, it should work

Comment: you will have to replace H, M, and C with actual data. You could use `dput()` to copy a subset of these three files in your post.

Comment: Ok ill work on it, one of the data sets has quite a few variables.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/wood2174/mapkickstarter/data

Comment: I tried adding part of my data sets to a public site, the data has hundreds of thousands of lines so i just took cuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a brute force way that i fixed this issue. Below I i posted the three updated functions that made this work. I found that when making a choropleth each state is assigned a point number but not a name, so i used if loops to assign each point number the appropriate name. The name was then able to pass to the function and now give me the desired output.

[image]

This is when i clicked on New York and this works for any state that is clicked on.

Three revised functions Code:

```
   CT <- function(r,data,pop){

    cali <- map_data("county") %>%
      filter(region == r)

    cali_pop <- left_join(cali, pop, by = c("subregion","region"))

    cali_pop$pop_cat <- with(cali_pop,
                             (paste0(cali_pop$subregion, "<br />",
                                     round(cali_pop$MedianBackers), "Median Backers ||",round(cali_pop$MedianUSD),"MedianUSD","<br />",
                                     round(cali_pop$MeanBackers), "Mean Backers ||",round(cali_pop$MeanUSD),"MeanUSD","<br />",
                                     (cali_pop$TotalBackers), "Total Backers ||",(cali_pop$TotalUSD), "TotalUSD")))
    cali_pop[is.na(cali_pop)] <- 0
    cali_pop$pop_cat <- as.factor(cali_pop$pop_cat)



    p <- cali_pop %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~long, y = ~lat, color = ~as.factor(TotalUSD), colors = c('#ffeda0','#f03b20'), text = ~pop_cat) %>%
      add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4),showlegend = FALSE) %>%
      add_polygons(
        fillcolor = 'transparent',
        line = list(color = 'black', width = 0.5),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>%
      layout(
        title = "Backers by County",
        titlefont = list(size = 10),
        xaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE,
                     zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
        yaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE,
                     zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
      )
    p

  }  

  output$Smap <- renderPlotly({
    M$hover <- with(M, paste("State:",State))
    # give state boundaries a white border
    l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = 'usa',
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("grey83"),
      subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white"),
      showsubunits = TRUE,
      showcountries = TRUE,
      resolution = 50,
      projection = list(type = 'albers usa',
                        rotation = list(lon = -100)),
      lonaxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(-140,-55),
        dtick = 5
      ),
      lataxis = list(
        showgrid = TRUE,
        gridwidth = 0.5,
        range = c(15, 70),
        dtick = 5
      )
    )

    # Plotting a US interactive map
    p <- plot_ly(M,source = "CCM",
        z = ~ M$`Mean Bakers`,
        text = ~ M$hover,
        type = 'choropleth',
        locations = ~ M$code,
        locationmode = "USA-states"
      ) %>%
      colorbar(title = "Money") %>%
      layout(
        title = 'Kickstarter USA',
        geo = g
      )
    p
  })

  output$Cmap <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "CCM")

    if(s$pointNumber == 4) {
      d = "colorado"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 3) {
      d = "california"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 43) {
      d = "utah"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 26) {
      d = "nevada"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 43) {
      d = "utah"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 1) {
      d = "arizona"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 36) {
      d = "oregon"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 46) {
      d = "washington"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 10) {
      d = "idaho"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 24) {
      d = "montana"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 49) {
      d = "wyoming"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 29) {
      d = "new mexico"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 42) {
      d = "texas"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 35) {
      d = "oklahoma"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 14) {
      d = "kansas"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 25) {
      d = "nebraska"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 40) {
      d = "south dakota"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 33) {
      d = "north dakota"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 21) {
      d = "minnestota"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 13) {
      d = "iowa"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 23) {
      d = "missouri"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 2) {
      d = "arkansas"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 16) {
      d = "louisiana"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 48) {
      d = "wisconsin"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 11) {
      d = "illinois"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 12) {
      d = "indiana"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 20) {
      d = "michigan"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 34) {
      d = "ohio"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 37) {
      d = "pennsylvania"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 30) {
      d = "new york"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 44) {
      d = "vermont"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 27) {
      d = "new hampshire"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 17) {
      d = "maine"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 19) {
      d = "massachusetts"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 38) {
      d = "road island"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 5) {
      d = "connecticut"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 28) {
      d = "new jersey"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 6) {
      d = "delaware"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 18) {
      d = "maryland"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 47) {
      d = "west virginia"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 45) {
      d = "virginia"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 15) {
      d = "kentucky"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 41) {
      d = "tennessee"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 32) {
      d = "north carolina"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 39) {
      d = "south carolina"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 9) {
      d = "georgia"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 8) {
      d = "florida"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 0) {
      d = "alabama"
    }
    if(s$pointNumber == 22) {
      d = "mississippi"
    }
    else {
      plotly_empty()
    }

    CT(d,H,C)

  })
```